# KSDS file - Duplicate key error in Ditto utility

Tags: cobol, mainframe, zos, jcl, vsam

> This is my KSDS creation JCL.

```
000100 //VSAMKSDS JOB CLASS=A,MSGCLASS=A,MSGLEVEL=(1,1),PRTY=15,      
000200 //             NOTIFY=&SYSUID                                  
000300 //STEP10 EXEC PGM=IDCAMS                                       
000400 //SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                         
000500 //SYSIN DD *                                                   
000600         DEFINE CLUSTER(                 -                      
000700                   NAME(RAHUL.KSDS.FILE) -                      
000800                   INDEXED               -                      
000900                   KEYS(01 05)           -                      
001000                   RECSZ(50 50)          -                      
001100                   FREESPACE(10 20)      -                      
001200                   TRACKS(50 30)         -                      
001300                   CISZ(8192)            -                      
001400                   VOLUME(ZASYS1))                              
001500 /*
```

> This is the records which I am trying to enter and save
> [image]

This is error, Which I am getting
DIT3750I VSAM PUT RC X'08', Error Code X'08' (duplicate key)

Whenever I am trying to save more than one record, I am getting duplicate key errors.
even if the key value is not same, still same error again and again.
please help to resolve this.

Comment: Syntax for `KEYS` is "KEYS(length  offset)" - so your key is 1 byte long starting in column 6? Sounds strange...

Answer (score 3):

Your KEYS specification is backwards.  Yours is on the first space, I think you wanted KEYS(5 0)
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=commands-define-cluster